# Unable to find any information regarding this fact (Frey, elliptic curves)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Frey states in 'Links between stable elliptic curves and certain Diophantine equations' the following

"The most important fact about elliptic curves with reduction of muItipIicative type is due to Tate: Let K be a finite extension field of the field $\mathbb{Q}_l$  of $l$-adic numbers with $\delta_E \in K^{\times2}$ ($\delta$ the Hasse invariant)  and assume that E has reduction of multiplicative type mod $l$. Then the group of K-rational points of E, E(K), is analytically isomorphic to $\frac{K}{<q>}$
where q, the $l$-adic period of E, is an element in $G_l$ with
$j_E = \frac{1}{q}  + \sum\limits_{i\geq 0} a_iq^i$ . The e1ements a_i are the integers occurring in the usual Fourier expansion of the (classical) j-function over $\mathbb{C}$ (with $q= e^{2\pi\tau i}$)."

I have been able to find some related information on different areas, for example the quotient of a field K by $<q>$ but nothing that relates the torsion points and the j-invariant in any way. The way that he introduces it makes it seem as though there is an important paper on the subject.

Source: G.Frey, Links between stable elliptic curves and certain Diophantine equations, Ann.Univ. Saraviensis, 1(1986), 1-40

Comment: I think this question fits better in Overflow

Comment: Ok, thanks I shall.

Comment: Just one tiny thing: the $\;j$- invariant gives us a way to parametrize up to isomorphism elliptic curves over an algebraic closed field (I'm entering here troubled waters as I'm used to work with the complex $\;\Bbb C\;$ , complex toruses and stuff). I'm not sure whether there's some *direct*  relation between it and torsion points on the elliptic curve other than what you can deduce from the torsion group itself in the isomorphism class of the curve. Perhaps I'm talking non-sense here, but hey! Wouldn't be my first time.

Comment: Answered:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196162/unable-to-find-any-information-regarding-this-fact-frey-elliptic-curves/196165#196165